# new with pygame. My button doesnt work. why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Ignore `AmountOfPlayers()` function.
Im new with pygame and my button doesn't do anything. why? How can I improve my code with pygame?

```py
while True:
    pygame.init()
    size=(1440,810)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption("POCKER SFAHOT")
    welcomeimage = 'welcome.png'
    imgwelcome = pygame.image.load(welcomeimage)
    screen.blit(imgwelcome, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if (300 <= mouse[0] <= 1150) and (600 <= mouse[1] <= 470):
                AmountOfPlayers()
    pygame.event.get()
```

Comment: For what values of `mouse[1]` will `600 <= mouse[1] <= 470` be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `600 <= mouse[1] <= 470` is always `False`, because 600 is never less than 470. It has to be `470 <= mouse[1] <= 600`:

<s>`if (300 <= mouse[0] <= 1150) and (600 <= mouse[1] <= 470):`</s>

```py
if (300 <= mouse[0] <= 1150) and (470 <= mouse[1] <= 600):
```

However, I recommend using [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint). See the example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
size=(1440,810)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("POCKER SFAHOT")
welcomeimage = 'welcome.png'
imgwelcome = pygame.image.load(welcomeimage).convert_alpha()

welcome = True
run = True

while run:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            rect = pygame.Rect(300, 370, 850, 130)
            if welcome and rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                welcome = False
                
    if welcome:
        screen.blit(imgwelcome, (0,0))
    else:
        screen.fill(0)
        AmountOfPlayers()
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize pygame only once, but call `pygame.init()` in the event loop. Move all initialization before `while True:` loop and leave only the code that handles events in the loop.